# ios nsdictionary low avg high

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

Right now I'm taking my `NSDictionary` and running a *loop* of all values to find the low, high, and *calculate* average.

Since I'm **new** to `IOS` I wanted to ask if there is a better way to do this. Is there? *Thanks*.

Comment: Edit your question and paste in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact answer to this question depends on what type of objects are in your NSDictionary. The answer in general is that you can probably use Key-Value Coding operators to do what you want. Here is an example:

```
NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSNumber *two = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
NSNumber *three = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:one, @"apple", two, @"orange", three, @"pear", nil];
NSLog(@"The max number is %@", [[dictionary allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"]);
NSLog(@"The min number is %@", [[dictionary allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"]);
NSLog(@"The mean is %@", [[dictionary allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.intValue"]);
```

This is probably no more efficient than enumerating things yourself, but it is more concise.

If the contents of your NSDictionary are objects of a custom class that have an NSNumber as a property, you can still use this method by placing the property name after the `@avg`, e.g. `@avg.myProperty`. Note that these `valueForKeyPath` methods return NSNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a better way to do it than how you're already doing it by enumerating the dictionary. This is mainly because `NSDictionary` contains opaque objects. They might be `NSString`s, they might be `NSNumber`s or they might be `CHZLolCat`s. They can be anything. So it wouldn't make sense to have a low, high and average method as not everything has the concept of a low, high and average.

However if you showed us some code we might be able to offer specific advice on the actual method of enumeration.